# Submit a form on condition that atleast one drop-down option is selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, validation

I have a form with 8 select (drop-down) fields. I need to the form to be successfully submitted only when at least 1 option from the 8 select fields has been selected. If none of the options is selected, I need an alert to pop-up when the user tries to submit without selecting at least one option.

I have no knowledge in javascript or php.

I hope I'm clear enough.

Thanks guys.

Comment: do you have 8 dropdown inputs or one dropdown input with 8 options ?

Comment: I have 8 drop down inputs on the same form. I need atleast one option from atleast one dropdown to be selected before the form can be submitted.

Comment: if so then answer given by **Wissam El-Kik** will full-fill your need. Select that answer.

Comment: Wissam El-Kik's answer was efficient. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R99EC/2/).

Here's the code:

```
<select class="dropdown1">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
<select class="dropdown2">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
<select class="dropdown3">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
<select class="dropdown4">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
<select class="dropdown5">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
<select class="dropdown6">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
<select class="dropdown7">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
<select class="dropdown8">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
<button class="submit-btn">Submit</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".submit-btn").click(function(){
        var dropdown_selected = false;
        // Select all the selected dropdown values
        var dropdown_values_arr = new Array();
        dropdown_values_arr.push($(".dropdown1 option:selected").val());
        dropdown_values_arr.push($(".dropdown2 option:selected").val());
        dropdown_values_arr.push($(".dropdown3 option:selected").val());
        dropdown_values_arr.push($(".dropdown4 option:selected").val());
        dropdown_values_arr.push($(".dropdown5 option:selected").val());
        dropdown_values_arr.push($(".dropdown6 option:selected").val());
        dropdown_values_arr.push($(".dropdown7 option:selected").val());
        dropdown_values_arr.push($(".dropdown8 option:selected").val());
        // Loop over these values
        for(var i=0; i<dropdown_values_arr.length; i++){
            // If the value is not empty, then break the loop
            // Condition is met: at least one dropdown is selected
            if(dropdown_values_arr[i].length > 0){
                dropdown_selected = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // If there's no selected values in any of the dropdowns, then throw an alert message
        if(dropdown_selected == false){
            alert("Please fill at least one dropdown");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand your question, but if I'm correct, you want to check if something is selected in a drop-down box? (select)

Javascript (no JQ)

```
function checkdropdown() {
  if(document.getElementById('select').value != "") {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

HTML code

```
<form action='file.php' action='post'>
  <select name='select' id='select'>
    <option value=''>Select an option</option>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
    <option value='6'>6</option>
    <option value='7'>7</option>
    <option value='8'>8</option>
  </select>
<input type='submit' onClick='if(!checkdropdown()) {alert("You need to select a value!"); return false;}' value='Submit form' />
</form>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KNd47/